# How to fill input fields with an ajax request from MySQL server using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have an input field that I am trying to fill with an AJAX request to my SQL server using PHP, but it is not working. The console.log spits out the proper array title: ""
description: "", but it doesnt add the data to the text input field so I can see it. Ive looked at other answers, but they do not suffice. Thanks!
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext" name="task-title-reg" value="">
<textarea class="textbox" name="task-description-reg" rows="4" cols="50" value=""></textarea>
```

**AJAX REQUEST**

```
                $(".task-listing").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'task-info-get.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $("task-title-reg").val(response);
            $("task-description-reg").val(response);
        }
                })
            });
            });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title,description FROM tasks WHERE pid='.$_POST['pid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title,$description);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output[]=array(
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $description

    );
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;

$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `#$task-title-reg` what does `$` do here?

Comment: Its just what I've been trying. I removed them now

Comment: Do you know that `$('#` selects markup element by `id` attribute?

Comment: thats what I thought, i just ried using ".task-title-reg" and "task-title-reg" with no avail

Comment: There are a few issues here. 1) `$("task-title-reg")` is not a valid selector, use eg `$('.inputtext')` (same problem for your textarea); 2) `....val(response);` - your `response` is a JSON object, you want just one element in each input field.  Try `.val(response.title);`, and similar for description. 3) `$output[]=array(..)` - creates a multi-dimensional array, which isn't necessary here.  `$output=array(...)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the class to to input the value.

`$('.inputtext').val('Your value here!')`

Comment: it just says [object Object] if i do $('.inputtext').val(response); I need to convert from object to ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;
```

Due to above code and `dataType:'JSON'`, response is javascript Object.

Access strings by providing `keys` to javascript Object:

```
function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $(".task-title-reg").val(response.title);
            $(".task-description-reg").val(response.description);
        }
```